# Why setting visibility fails for Views with animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

An `ImageView` is animated with a rotate animation :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Test extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ImageView mIcon;
    private Animation mRotate;
    private boolean mShown = true;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mIcon = new ImageView(this);
        mIcon.setImageDrawable(
              getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
              );
        mIcon.setOnClickListener(this);

        setContentView(mIcon);


        mRotate = new RotateAnimation(
                  0f,360f,
                  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2,
                  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()/2
                  );
        mRotate.setDuration(2000);
        mRotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        mRotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        mRotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

        mIcon.setAnimation(mRotate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(mShown){
            mRotate.cancel();
            mIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            mIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mRotate.reset();
            mRotate.start();
        }
        mShown = !mShown;
    }
}
```

The part `mProgress.setVisibility(GONE);`  doesn't work. The `ImageView` doesn't hides at all. If I don't set the `Animation` for it, it works well.

My question is: **why the animated view's visibility is not changing ?**

UPDATE:
Wrapping the View in a `FrameLayout` and setting `FrameLayout`'s visibilty works. But still, this is an ugly workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I think it works as it should. Let me explain. Important thing here is **how** your `ImageView` is animated. If you use for example `TranslateAnimation` (I guess this is your case) then the view you animate doesn't in fact change position, it is only moved elsewhere on the screen, so for example if you animate button this way and want to click it, you still have to click on its previous location. So in this case I think your `ImageView` is `GONE`, but you see only drawing made by animation.
Using `ObjectAnimator` should solve this problem, because contrary to other animations it actually moves the view.

Comment: It's a rotate animation (updated in question). I'm thinking along the same lines , but after the animation is cancelled, and visibility set to GONE, I believe that area must be re-drawn (because the view there is just not visible anymore). So, it's hard to digest that this is just a leftover of animator's rendered view.

Comment: I've updated question with a standalone activity, you may run it and see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

try

mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

instead of

mProgress.setVisibility(GONE);

Answer (score 0):

Try to set mRotate.setFillAfter(false). your views visibility is really gone but the final state of your animation keeps its position.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing mIcon.clearAnimation() before you set the visibility to GONE.